# how to get plain text from <ejs-richtexteditor> using form control ? i'm unable to get it.text saving in <p> xyz</p> formet

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, rich-text-editor, form-control

how to get plain text from  using form control ? i'm unable to get it.text saving in forgraph formet  using form control . i seen documentaion to get string using getText(); but unable to implement this how to implement and where to write?

also not supporting .so I'm unable to write required validation. i wrote like bellow and showing at page load time

```
   <mat-list-item>                      
     <ejs-richtexteditor #toolsRTE id='faq_question' [toolbarSettings]='tools' placeholder="Question" showCharCount="true" minlength ="13" maxLength="100" required formControlName="question:getText();" >
      </ejs-richtexteditor>
      </mat-list-item>


 <mat-error *ngIf="faqForm.controls['question'].hasError('required')">
          Question is <strong>required</strong>
     </mat-error>


if (this.faqForm.valid ) {
            const faq: Faq = {
                Id: 0,
                CategoryId: this.faqForm.get('categoryType').value,
                FAQTopic: this.faqForm.get('question').value,
                FAQBody: this.faqForm.get('answer').value,
                IsActive: true
            };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you couldn’t find an easier way, this can help you

```js
const question = '<p style="color: red">Hello World</p>';

const quesionHtml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(question, 'text/html');
const htmlAsString = quesionHtml.body.innerHTML;
console.log(htmlAsString);
```

Comment: Glad to help @user2564537

Comment: Ashot Aleqsanyan I'm not able get bold strick and color property if I use the above scenario then what is using of rich text editor?

Comment: @user2564537 in that case you need to store the html value instead of text

Comment: Ashot Aleqsanyan could u please let me know about it?

Comment: @user2564537 sorry I don't understand?

Comment: i mean how to get html value and pass to form obeject for save ?

Comment: @user2564537 let me clarify, if you want to save text without tags you can use the code from my example.
If you need to save the styles, you need to save the html code as string instead of text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205675/discussion-between-user2564537-and-ashot-aleqsanyan).

Comment: @user2564537 I have updated answer. but I think your code should return the html as string

Answer (score 0):

shortly

```
<ejs-richtexteditor formControlName="question" ...>
</ejs-richtexteditor>
```

in your component

```
 if (this.faqForm.valid ) {
    const {question, answer, categoryType } = this.faqForm.value
    const faq: Faq = {
        Id: 0,
        CategoryId: categoryType,
        FAQTopic: question,
        FAQBody: answer,
        IsActive: true
    };

}
```

you can check this link https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/rich-text-editor/validation/

Comment: feyzullah yildiz still getting text like <p>How to get My Password</p> I need to get without <p>. could u please suggest this way?

Comment: using view child i can get one value i have 2 editor in form how to get second one also ?

Comment: You can use ViewChildren

Comment: feyzullah yıldız I'm getting single form control value using view child, I have 2 rich text editors there how to manage it?

Answer (score -1):

This problem occurs whenever the module is applied inside material tags as: mat-formField

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).